# In CoffeeScript, is there an 'official' way to interpolate a string at run-time instead of when compiled?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, template-engine, coffeekup

I have an options object in my CS class, and I'd like to keep some templates in it:

```
class MyClass
    options:
        templates:
            list: "<ul class='#{ foo }'></ul>"
            listItem: "<li>#{ foo + bar }</li>"
            # etc...
```

Then I'd like to interpolate these strings **later** in the code... But of course these are compiled to `"<ul class='" + foo +"'></ul>"`, and foo is undefined.

Is there an official CoffeeScript way to do this at run-time using `.replace()`?

---

Edit: I ended up writing a little utility to help:

```
# interpolate a string to replace {{ placeholder }} keys with passed object values
String::interp = (values)->
    @replace /{{ (\w*) }}/g,
        (ph, key)->
            values[key] or ''
```

So my options now look like:

```
templates:
    list: '<ul class="{{ foo }}"></ul>'
    listItem: '<li>{{ baz }}</li>'
```

And then later in the code:

```
template = @options.templates.listItem.interp
    baz: foo + bar
myList.append $(template)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'd say, if you need delayed evaluation, then they should probably be defined as functions.

Perhaps taking the values individually:

```
templates:
    list: (foo) -> "<ul class='#{ foo }'></ul>"
    listItem: (foo, bar) -> "<li>#{ foo + bar }</li>"
```

Or from a context object:

```
templates:
    list: (context) -> "<ul class='#{ context.foo }'></ul>"
    listItem: (context) -> "<li>#{ context.foo + context.bar }</li>"
```

---

Given your now-former comments, you could use the 2nd example above like so:

```
$(options.templates.listItem foo: "foo", bar: "bar").appendTo 'body'
```

Comment: Thanks again for the update. Your solution looks a little cleaner than my `String::interp` thing. Would your way also perform better because it doesn't use regex or is that a non-issue? I may be doing this in very large loops.

Comment: For anyone else who may find this useful, Jonathan's method performs much better than mine: http://jsperf.com/string-concat-vs-regex-replace